# Correct Mesh Deformations?

Tags: mesh, materials

I created a Mesh of a 3D letter "P"
However, in order to have the open space in the middle of the Mesh I needed to have more than one face on the very top, which causes the material to look unrealistic. (I circled the deformities)
[image]
So I am not sure if this is possible, but I want the mesh to have a clean top. I changed the shading to flat, which did make the top have a clean cut finish, but the siding did not have the look I was going for.

Is this possible?
Here is the blender file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ye5m8oj9p51lz7w/01.blend?dl=0

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polygons with more than 4 sides (ngons) do not subdivide well.

Instead of one big ngon on top like this:

[image]

try to fill your mesh with quads:

[image]

First delete the faces that have more than 4 vertices:

[image]

Add a few loop cuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) that match the vertices on the joints of your mesh.

[image]

Then fill the gaps making quads.

[image]

Your mesh should be nice and smooth now. Even with smooth shading or a Subdivision surface modifier.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! When I tried to do this myself, for some reason the material would be rotated a different direction for some of the faces. Probably me just being a noob again XD Anyway, I just downloaded your blend file and it works great!

Comment: Yes... I changed the UVs using **Smart UV Project** and also changed the coordinates on the material to use the UV as coordinates.

Comment: Thanks again, I want to add more letter, but when I go into edit mode the whole structure moves. What setting do I need to turn off? (I'm using your .blend file BTW)